# Main folder empty when importing from Github into eclipse

Tags: eclipse

I downloaded and imported a repository into eclipse from Github, and built/assembled/set up the necessary folders. I can see them in my file manager, but I cannot see them in eclipse. the "Main" folder is empty. It looks like this: \n
[image]

How can I get eclipse to realise that the main folder is not empty?

Comment: Is It a maven project? It really depends on the project.

Comment: You can have several ways of importing It. The easiest Is import folder and select It. You should give more details on your question so we can help you

Comment: `src/main/` contains by default source folders that are shown on the project level (at the same level as `src`, not inside of `src/main/`) in the _Project Explorer_ and _Package Explorer_ views.